# System.FormatException while Reading File

Tags: c#

Visual Studio puts me an Exception on this line but why ?

```
 RechenKontostand = Convert.ToDouble(File.ReadAllText(pathkonto));
```

The Exception is:

> System.FormatException wrong Format

If you need more Code just ask!

Nothin of the other answers solve my Problem so it isn´t a duplicate

Comment: Do you want to show us what `File.ReadAllText(pathkonto)` returns exactly?

Comment: This is *expected behaviour* if file's content doesn't represent any double value, e.g. `bla-bla-bla`. What is the content then?

Comment: Technically, the exception is "while" `Convert.ToDouble` and *after* the entire contents of the file is returned as one string.

Comment: Read [ask], create a [mcve]. The file is isrrelevant, its contents are.

Comment: @knuVe Please show the result of Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(pathkonto));

Comment: As for your edit, it definitely is a duplicate. Again, read the file into a separate string, then create a [mcve] with that string. Then you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because the string passed to `Convert.ToDouble` was not in an acceptable format. When you pass a string to this method, it ends up calling `double.Parse`

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx) explains that a `FormatException` is raised when:

> s does not represent a number in a valid format.